# Extracting MultiValuesToPoints yields identical value for each band?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1

I'm attempting to extract hyperspectral remote sensing data to a point featureclass using the ExtractMultiValuesToPoints ArcGIS tool.

The value of each band (228 bands) should be appended as a field to each point in the input feature class. The problem is: each appended field contain identical values for each point.

So it seems that only the value of the first band is extracted and assigned to each next band.

I've scripted the tool as follows.

```
import arcpy
import os
inRasts= "L:/MyData/StudySite.IMG"
fcDir= "L:/MyData/Geo.gdb"
fcIn= "Plots"
inPoint= os.path.join(fcDir, fcIn)
arcpy.sa.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(in_point_features= inPoint, in_rasters= inRasts, bilinear_interpolate_values= "NONE")
```

The Remote sensing image properties are:

- data type: File System Raster
- Format: IMAGINE Image
- pixel type: floating point
- Admittedly, the raster data may be a bit weird. The NoData pixels have a pixel value of -3.40282346639e+038 I don't quite know how I ended up with that, must be a rounding error somewhere.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 on W7 computer. I cannot find any service packs installed.

Comment: What version and service pack of ArcGIS are you running? There have been known bugs with this tool is previous versions (pre 10.0 SP4).

Comment: I echo what Radar mentioned.  Have you inspected the raster bands and found realistic values?  Are you open to using R to extract the values?

Comment: Hi Radar & Aaron, I've included the requested info. As you can see, the NoData value is a bit weird and this may cause the problems. I'll try the tool again on another raster. I'd definitely be interested to learn how to do this in R! I'm much more confident in R than ArcGIS.